# Possible faulty PSU?

Tags: boot, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

I had power ran out on me on Sunday while the PC was on and since the the OS (Windows 10) kept losing power as soon as I put stress on it. Not shutting down, losing power and then rebooting. I looked up online and people say it was most likely an overheating issue. I check every sensor, logged in every temp, nothing out of the ordinary. Tried it today again, put some stress on the system now I can't really get it too boot Windows properly, it looses power before even I can log in.

When I enter the bios (MB Asus Prime z790-A) every temp seems okay but... The 12V rail on the PSU is waaaay above 12V ([PSU Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ2ai.jpg)). Now is this the issue that's causing the system to lose power? Is it as easy as replace the PSU (Corsair RB 850w)?

The entire hardware is a month old, can realistically a blackout cause a brand new PSU to go bad as quickly as that? I had a generic 650w that's still kicking after 5 years and a Corsair goes out like this? Is this my issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Electronic equipment can fail quickly or last a good long time. No telling what might happen. Return under warranty.

Comment: I wonder if you had a power surge and not just a power cut. Consider getting a surge protector if you don’t have one already

Comment: @JamesP funny thing is, I do have one. It would make much more sense to be a surge rather than a cut but alas probably the suge protector is faulty as well... Seems like I also should invest in the UPS I've been postponing since forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 12V rail on the PSU is waaaay above 12v

Your photo shows 13.6v, which is ***not*** good... the tolerance specified by the ATX specification is ±5% for each rail... i.e: 11.4v (min) to 12.6v (max). What you're seeing is over +13%, which is very far out of spec.

This poor regulation could very likely be due to the power supply failing, and could also cause damage over the longer term.

> The entire hardware is a month old

I'd suggest you turn the PC off, remove the power supply and RMA it. If you can possibly help it, *do not use the PC in its current state at all*.

> can realistically a blackout cause a brand new PSU to go bad as quickly as that?

It may or may not be related... either way, avoid using that power supply wherever possible.

The "[*Bathtub curve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve)" is an interesting phenomenon, and is worth familiarising yourself with.

[image: bathtub curve, showing early failures, and wear out failures, with a low point in the middle]

Comment: Wow thank you so much for such an insightful comment. I'm not very well versed in the power aspect of computing and as such I had no idea the number was such a big deal. Honestly, thank you! PSU is already packed back in it's original case and I've already started the warranty process. It's sucks to be without a PC for an undefined period of time but at least all the other components were not affected by it.